# Number of binary trees that have the given inorder sequence

Tags: data-structures, binary-tree, binary-search-tree, permutation

I got this question in test series:

> Five nodes labeled P, Q, R, S, T are used to construct a binary tree. Determine the number of distinct binary trees that can be formed such that each of those in-order traversal gives P, Q, R, S, T.

I do not know the exact answer. The solution they have given was incorrect. How to solve such problems?

Comment: GOClasses test series?

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways to construct a binary (search) tree with  values -- such that the inorder traversal gives them in their proper order -- is the same as the number of binary tree *shapes* you can make with  nodes (so here the values play no role).

This is the case because for every shape of binary tree there is exactly one way to label the nodes with  values such that the inorder traversal gives the desired order.

The number of shapes of a binary tree with  nodes is the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) for the same , quoting Wikipedia:

> is the number of full binary trees with  + 1 leaves, or, equivalently, with a total of  internal nodes

What are called internal nodes here, map to all the nodes of our binary trees.

For your concrete case  is 5, and  is 42.

I list the 14 trees that have P as root:

```
P          P          P         P        P
 \          \          \         \        \
  Q          Q          Q         Q        Q
   \          \          \         \        \
    R          R          T         T        S
     \          \        /         /        / \
      S          T      R         S        R   T
       \        /        \       /
        T      S          S     R
        
P           P         P         P
 \           \         \         \
  R           R         S         S
 / \         / \       / \       / \
Q   S       Q   T     Q   T     R   T
     \         /       \       /
      T       S         R     Q
      
      
P         P         P         P        P
 \         \         \         \        \  
  T         T         T         T        T
 /         /         /         /        /
Q         Q         S         S        R
 \         \       /         /        / \
  R         S     Q         R        Q   S
   \       /       \       /
    S     R         R     Q
```

...5 with Q as root

```
  Q          Q          Q         Q        Q
 / \        / \        / \       / \      / \
P   R      P   R      P   T     P   T    P   S
     \          \        /         /        / \
      S          T      R         S        R   T
       \        /        \       /
        T      S          S     R
```

...4 with R as root

```
    R           R         R            R
   / \         / \       / \         /   \
  Q   S       Q   T     P   S       P     T
 /     \     /   /       \   \       \   /
P       T   P   S         Q   T       Q S
```

...5 with S as root

```
      S         S         S         S        S
     / \       / \       / \       / \      / \
    R   T     R   T     P   T     P   T    Q   T
   /         /           \         \      / \
  Q         P             Q         R    P   R
 /           \             \       /
P             Q             R     Q
```

...and 14 with T as root:

```
        T       T       T       T       T
       /       /       /       /       /
      S       S       S       S       S
     /       /       /       /       /
    R       R       P       P       Q
   /       /         \       \     / \
  Q       P           Q       R   P   R
 /         \           \     /
P           Q           R   Q


      T        T        T        T
     /        /        /        /
    R        R        Q        Q
   / \      / \      / \      / \
  Q   S    P   S    P   R    P   S
 /          \            \      /
P            Q            S    R


    T       T      T        T        T
   /       /      /        /        /
  P       P      P        P        P
   \       \      \        \        \
    S       S      Q        Q        R
   /       /        \        \      / \
  R       Q          R        S    Q   S
 /         \          \      /
Q           R          S    R
```

42 in total.

Comment: Great point, my answer assumes the question is about *balanced* binary search trees, whereas "balanced" was not actually specified in the OP.  I think your answer is better if we aren't able to ask for clarification about whether the tree is balanced.

Comment: sir, did you manually draw all these trees, or there's any cmd line utility to do the same?

Comment: I'm afraid I made them manually :/

Answer (score 0):

First, observe that a *complete* binary search tree has only a single possible arrangement.  For example with seven nodes and the requirement that in-order traversal is sorted alphabetically:

```
   D
 B   F
A C E G
```

But your problem is with 5 nodes, so the tree is not complete.  Here is one possible such tree:

```
   S
 Q   T
P R
```

Reading from left to right, the letters are in the correct order, but clearly not the only possible order.  Here's another one:

```
   R
 Q   T
P   S
```

There will always be exactly two empty leaves out of four possible leaf nodes.  If we use 1 to denote a populated leaf and 0 to denote empty, the possibilities are:

```
0011
0101
1001
1100
1010
0110
```

That is "4 choose 2" which gives six different trees.  The last question is whether there are two distinct trees with the same nodes populated but having different values (letters) at some nodes.  The answer is no, that is not possible, for the same reason as with a complete tree: swapping any two values would always make the tree out of order.  Just like in an array, there is only one ordering which is sorted when the values are all distinct.